# XDebug with Mamp doesn't work in NetBeans

Tags: php, netbeans, mamp, xdebug

I have used XDebug semi-sucessfully with PhpStorm and Mamp, but now I want to try using NetBeans for a project. But I can't get NetBeans to connect to XDebug. It just waits until I stop the debugger and then I get a message that NetBeans never got a connection to XDebug, and it asks me to check the settings in php.ini.

Now, as I said it has worked ok with PhpStorm, so I don't think there should be anything wrong with the settings in php.ini, but anyway, here they are:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp 
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

One thing that I found strange was that everyone talks about php.ini being located in /Applications/Mamp/conf, but in that folder there is no php.ini in my setup at least. In /Applications/Mamp/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf on the other hand, there is. So that's the one I have modified. And since it works in PhpStorm I figure it must be right...

But then, why isn't NetBeans able to connect? I'm also using the XDebug plugin for Safari to hook it up in the browser. And the port in NetBeans is set to 9000 as in the php.ini file.

I'm using NetBeans 7.0.1 and php5.3.6.

Anything else I'm missing?

EDIT:

Well, I found the problem for why XDebug wasn't connecting anyway: I am using the add-in for Safari for XDebug, and apparently it had it's own setting for IDE Key, set to 1, while NetBeans had netbeans-xdebug set. Once I changed it to the latter in the add-in I got a connection. The problem is I still get some sort of error. It says: 404 Page not found when I hit the debugger, and the address in the address field is: http://localhost/app_netbeans/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug

Any idea what is going on here?

BTW, just hitting run inside NetBeans works fine and opens http://localhost/app_netbeans (I have used mod_rewrite to remove the index.php part of urls in CodeIgniter)

EDIT 2: 
I found that the index.php part of the address was because in the run configuration in NetBeans there was an "index file" setting that was set by default to index.php. If I removed that to have CodeIgniter "controller" urls without the index.php I got the correct url, but with the xdebu stuff appended after it. But still I get the 404 Page not found when I use the debugger command, but not when I use the run command.

Weirdly enough what I can do is I can hit debug, ignore the fact that it goes to 404 Page not found, and go back to the IDE, hit run and if I have a breakpoint set it will then stop at that breakpoint.

But again, this is not exactly what I would consider normal debugging behaviour... So if anyone knows what is going on I would love to hear it...

Comment: A vodedown without a comment...? What's up with that? I don't mind vodedowns if there is something wrong with my question, but please say what the problem is, whoever did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this config and make sure you update Netbeans to use port 9001.

```
[xdebug]

zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"

xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

I found that the port 9000 sometimes conflicts with other applications, and xdebug seems to fail silently if it cant use it.

Comment: Tried setting the Firewall off?

Comment: No, but please see my edits above in the question. I got the connection to work by changing the ide key in the Safari add-in. But I'm still getting weird behaviour...

Comment: The 404 is being returned by your app, xdebug is working fine.

Comment: Well, but it seems to be some problem with how xdebug, the ide and codeigniter work together... It seems in all examples I read a default page is expected (index.php) for the debugging somehow, and in codeigniter you don't have an index.php start page per se, but a start controller that loads a php page. But I can't seem to specify that correctly if that's the problem.

Comment: CodeIgniter is crappy at handling `$_GET` requests, I would suggest a better framework, like symfony, seriously. If you still wanna suffer with CI, try this search http://www.google.com.ar/search?q=_GET+codeigniter+XDebug.

Comment: Well, I didn't actually get the answer to my question, but I'll credit you with the bounty for the tip about get requests, since the bounty period is ending now, and I'll look further into that myself. Thanks.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you switching to symfony, CI is really easy to get you started, but overtime, you will realize that most of the features other (mature, widely supported, constantly updated, community backed, you name it)frameworks already support, are either missing of not correctly implement in CI.  There are of course other good options besides symfony, it's my suggestion if you are coming from CI. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code..

```
zend_extension="path to the xdebug.so"
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Module Settings ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

and also make sure the port in the netbeans is correct. you can check that in

1. goto tools menu and select options
2. in options click on the php and check the port number.

[image]

Comment: Didn't work... I have tried every combination I could find for this, including the variations found on xdebug.remote_enable=1, xdebug.remote_enable=on, etc... But what I did find was that there was no php interpreter set in the settings dialog. Strangely running the project (without debugging) still works. But I did set that to the MAMP php file now. Still didn't work. I also restarted the Apache server after every attempt to change the php.ini. But somehow I get the feeling Netbeans is using the wrong php still...

Comment: Check whether xdebug is configured correctly in your system by writing phpinfo() in a testfile if xdebug is found or not. if it is found try by changing the port.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is finally working, so I wanted to post my full php.ini configuration:

```
[xdebug]
; got this script from https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-mac-os.html
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_log="/Applications/MAMP/logs/xdebug_remote.log"
```

You may also check if your project is configured to copy to  a different directory in the Netbeans project settings. After I changed this setting I had to restart Netbeans and MAMP using the quit command.

Just to note:

- No index.php in my start up properties
- Stop at first line is turned off in debugging preferences
- I do think changing to port 9001 made a difference on my system